# Python seems to make every variable a float

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, int, fizzbuzz

I tried to write a simple fizzbuzz program in python, 
I tried to use `isinstance` to determine if a number is a `float` or a `int` instead of creating a list, but whenever I try it for some reason it considers every number to be a float is this a thing in python or a flaw in my logic?

```
i = 3
if isinstance(i/3,float) == False:
    print("Fizz")
else:
    print("???")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` operator returns a `float`. Even if the value could be expressed by an integer, you'll still get a `float`. E.g., `3/3` will return the `float` value of `1.0`. Instead, you could check the remainder directly using the `%` operator:

```
if i % 3 == 0:
    print("Fizz")
else:
    print("???")
```